# Regular expressions in Dreamweaver - producing a number sequence

Tags: html, regex, dreamweaver, number-sequence

I've got an HTML page with a long series of data in tabular format (2194 entries!), each starting with

```
<td id="foo"...>
```

I need each id to be unique, and so would like to use a regular expression in Dreamweaver's find and replace function to do this. Basically, it would look like this before:

```
<td id="foo"...>
<td id="foo"...>
<td id="foo"...>
```

and, using the regular expression, changed to:

```
<td id="001"...>
<td id="002"...>
<td id="003"...>
```

Is this possible? And, if so, what's the syntax of the expression?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Can you change this code? For example, can you use a class instead of an ID, or are you locked into the code that's already there?

Comment: You can't do this using Dreamweaver's regex. You need to to this in a programming language where the regex replacement can be a function.

Comment: All of the `<td>`'s already have classes, I'm afraid - it's for a CMS, which need the same class, but requires each editable tag to have a unique ID.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using something like a simple find/replace from a text editor, I'd run it through some kind of HTML DOM script. Here's some jQuery-ish **pseudocode**:

```
var tdList = source.find('td.foo');

for (i = 0; i < tdList.length; i++) {
     tdList[i].attr('id', 'foo' + i.padWithZeroes(length:3));
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the code. I've tried to put it in the head of my HTML document, in `<script>` tags, but it claims there's some kind of syntaxt error - a missing closing bracket after the argument. Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: @Andy - It's just a pseudocode example, and it's based on jQuery. Just trying to give you an idea of what to do. It should be close to working jQuery code, but you'd have to include the jQuery JS framework, and the `'td.foo'` selects td elements of class "foo". You could try `'td#foo'`, but since multiple elements with id "foo" would break validation, I don't know if that would work. Since you know your code better than I do, I suggest you write your own script in whatever language you're comfortable with, based on the above idea. You could also use a server-side script to rewrite the files.